# GET requests works only with params not just url

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, string-formatting

I've just discovered something strange. When downloading data from facebook with GET using the `requests 2.18.4` library, I get error when I just use

```
requests.get('https://.../{}/likes?acces_token={}'.format(userID,token))
```

into which I parse the user ID and access - the API does not read the access token correctly.

But, it works fine as

```
requests.get('https://../{}'.format(userID), params={"access_token":token})
```

Or it works when I copy paste the values in the appropriate fields by hand in the python console.

So my hypothesis is that it has something to with how the token string got parsed using the `params` vs the string. But what I don't understand at all, why would that be the case? Or is `?` character somehow strange in this case?

Comment: What error do you get? Please create some examples which can be tested.

Comment: 1st url: `http://.../x/likes?acces_token=y`, 2nd url: `http://.../x?access_token=y`

Answer (score 1):

Double check if both the URLs are the same (in your post they differ by the `/likes` substring).

Then you can check how the library `requests` concatenated parameters from the params argument:

```
    url = 'https://facebook.com/.../{}'.format(userID)
    r = requests.Request('GET', url, params={"access_token":token})
    pr = r.prepare()
    print pr.url
```